# Make an input negative on selection even if the input is blank

Tags: javascript

I just found out that Samsung user's keyboards don't have the option for a negative sign for number inputs. So this makes my user-input impossible to use properly for Samsung users. So I grafted an idea around this by allowing a select option to turn the user input to a negative. But this would assume the user has already put in a number.

I am only using client-side validation, and this is what I have so far:

```js
const unitsSelect = document.getElementById("unitsAcceleration"),
  gravityInput = document.getElementById("inputAcceleration");
unitsSelect.addEventListener("change", (evt) => {
  const unitSelected = unitsSelect.value;
  if (unitSelected === "-a") {
    gravityInput.value = -Math.abs(gravityInput.value);
  } else {
    gravityInput.value = "";
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="number" name="inputAcceleration" id="inputAcceleration">
    <select name="unitsAcceleration" id="unitsAcceleration">
    <option id="-a" value="-a">(negative value) - </option>
```

The issue only occurs if the user selects the negative input before putting in a number. So what I am trying to do is allow a person to select the negative and even if it is blank, the input will still be negative (this is all to help only Samsung users with the Samsung keyboard).

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd set the select to return +/-1 and then just multiply the input with the units to get the answer. Consider this:

```js
function acceleration()
{
return Number(document.getElementById("inputAcceleration").value)*Number(document.getElementById("unitsAcceleration").value);
}
const unitsSelect = document.getElementById("unitsAcceleration"),
  gravityInput = document.getElementById("inputAcceleration");
unitsSelect.addEventListener("change", () => console.log("number is ", acceleration()));
gravityInput.addEventListener("input", () => console.log("number is ", acceleration()));
```

```html
<input type="number" name="inputAcceleration" id="inputAcceleration">
    <select name="unitsAcceleration" id="unitsAcceleration">
    <option selected id="-a" value="1">(positive value)</option>
    <option id="-a" value="-1">(negative value)</option>
</select>
```